# Import data with double quotes using text qualifier throws error on other double quotes

Tags: sql-server, import, sql-server-2016

I am trying to import a flat file.

The file is delimited by a | and has double quotes around all fields i.e.

```
"name"|""|"30842"
```

I need to automate the import process to a temporary table then I use a merge statement to get the delta into the main table.

I cannot get the import to run as it throws an error on lines such as this:

```
"name"|"I have an "I" in my name"|"30892"
```

I assume its the double quotes around the I.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: How are you importing the file?

Comment: Sorry using task/import data/flat file

Comment: You may have to import it as a single string, then manipulate it in SQL. Its an invalid string as it is because the "I" should be ""I"". If you bring it as a single string, you can then add a | to the front and back, then substitute |" and "| for some other delimiter, and then parse it.

Comment: The file is not properly formed. As with CSV files, just with a different field delimiter character, quotes in field values need to be quoted themselves, i.e.: `"name"|"I have an ""I"" in my name"|"30892"`